# Looping through SerenityRest Response in JAVA

Tags: java, response, rest-assured, serenity-bdd

I am trying to get a count of all models from the cars object, which is part of a SerenityRest response.

```
Response response = SerenityRest.rest()
        .contentType("application/json")
        .when()
        .get("/api/");
if (response.statusCode() == 200) {
   int numUniqueModels = response.body().path("cars.size()");  // 3
}
```

Response:

```
   "cars": {
       "Acura": [
           "ILX",
           "MDX",
           "TLX"
       ],
       "Audi": [
           "A3",
           "A4",
           "A6",
           "A7"
       ],
       "BMW": [
           "x",
           "y"
       ]
   }
```

For example,

```
response.body().path("cars.size()") = 3,
```

but i need the sum of cars.Acura.size() + cars.Audi.size() + cars.BMW.size() to get all models. However, i don't know if the exact names Acura, Audi or BMW will exist in the response, since vehicles may change dynamically. To solve this, i will need to do some kind of a loop, where:

```
sum = 0; 
for (int i = 0; i < response.body().path("cars.size()"); i++) {
   sum += response.body().path("cars.[i].size()");
}
```

The sum should give a total number of car models = 9.
The problem is that this syntax: path("cars.[i].size()") is not correct. What is the correct call?

Comment: Can you provide a larger code sample so I can see the types?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to make complex request with rest-assured you have to follow the synthax described here [groovy gpath](http://groovy-lang.org/processing-xml.html#_gpath) as mentionned here [rest-assured doc](https://github.com/rest-assured/rest-assured/wiki/Usage#json-using-jsonpath):

> Note that the JsonPath implementation uses [Groovy's GPath](http://groovy-lang.org/processing-xml.html#_gpath) syntax and is not to be confused with Jayway's [JsonPath](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath) implementation.

So you have to play with some groovy synthax:

```
int total = JsonPath.from("{  "
              + " \"cars\": {\n"
              + "       \"Acura\": [\n"
              + "           \"ILX\",\n"
              + "           \"MDX\",\n"
              + "           \"TLX\"\n"
              + "       ],\n"
              + "       \"Audi\": [\n"
              + "           \"A3\",\n"
              + "           \"A4\",\n"
              + "           \"A6\",\n"
              + "           \"A7\"\n"
              + "       ],\n"
              + "       \"BMW\": [\n"
              + "           \"x\",\n"
              + "           \"y\"\n"
              + "       ]\n"
              + "   }"
              + "}")
        .getInt("cars.collect { it.value.size() }.sum()")
```

So this expression should make the job `cars.collect { it.value.size() }.sum()`. The `collect` method is like a map method in functional programming. So you map the collection `cars` HashMap with the `size()` of its values and you collect the `sum()`!

**Edit**

So you just have to do:

```
Response response = SerenityRest.rest()
        .contentType("application/json")
        .when()
        .get("/api/");
if (response.statusCode() == 200) {
   int numUniqueModels = response.body().path("cars.collect { it.value.size() }.sum()");  // 9
}
```

Comment: This is not going to work. I mentioned that the response is dynamic, which means that Acura, Audi or BMW may not be present. How am i going to construct int total = JsonPath.from(".....") if i don't know what's in it?

Comment: Did you tried it? JsonPath is the object used by the method `path(String)`. The expression iterate through the `cars` entries and collect the size of each. So this should work for any element. So you just have to do: `int numUniqueModels = response.body().path("cars.collect { it.value.size() }.sum()");  // 9`

Comment: you got it brother, i used the wrong syntax. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: np guy! That was funny to search for the solution ;)